# Nginx Rewrite Rule for infinitely long URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I am having a Rewrite Rule:

```
location / {
fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index   index.php;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include         fastcgi_params;

if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^/([^/]*)$ /index.php?category=$1 break;
rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?category=$1&post=$2 break;
rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?category=$1&post=$2 break;
rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?category=$1&post=$2&ucategory=$3 break;
rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?category=$1&post=$2&ucategory=$3&upost=$4 break;
rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?category=$1&post=$2&ucategory=$3&upost=$4;
return 200;
}
rewrite ^/$ /index.php break;}
```

It works great for URLs with a maximum of 4 subfolders.
For example:

example.com/1/2/3/4 will be example.com?category=1&post=2&ucategory=3&upost=4

But example.com/1/2/3/4/5 starts a download of a file called '5'

Any Idea to forbid the download? Or is there in nginx an optionen to create a rewrite pattern for endless subfolders?